# get value select ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

this is my view

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating style="color:red">Shipping Address</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="data.office_code" name="office_code" ([ngModel])="selectedItem" (ionChange)="onItemSelection(selection)">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let data of ofcode" [value]="data.office_code"> {{data.title_address}}
      </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

this is my controller

```
    public onItemSelection(selection) {
     if ( selection != undefined) { 
      ...
     } else {
      ...
     }
    }
```

how can I get the value from selected item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few errors in your code :

1. Remove `[(ngModel)]="data.office_code"` and
2. It's `[()]` not `([])` , Change `([ngModel])="selectedItem"` to `[(ngModel)]="selectedItem"`
3. Change `(ionChange)="onItemSelection(selection)"` to `(ionChange)="onItemSelection($event)"`

Your code block should look like this :

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating style="color:red">Shipping Address</ion-label>
    <ion-select name="office_code" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (ionChange)="onItemSelection($event)">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let data of ofcode" [value]="data.office_code"> {{data.title_address}}
        </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-select-address)**